# PHP - Force download or view in browser depending on file type

Tags: php

I am using the following headers to force a download but I need to try and have the browser display certain files like PDF's and JPG's if that is the file type, finding the exntension is easy enough but how can I alter these headers to open the file in the browser?

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
$header="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.";";
header($header);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Expires:0");
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-length: $filesize");
```

Comment: Change `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` for one.

Comment: Most browsers will not display application/octet-stream and will opt to download anyway. You'll need to set the correct content type (image/jpeg etc) for the files you want to display in-browser.

Comment: Can you please make an answer rather than comments as my question are being marked down and I'm threatened with being banned - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to display a file in the browser, you'll need to use the correct MIME type. You can set it yourself based on file extension, or you can use the [finfo module](http://php.net/fileinfo):

```
function getContentType($filename) {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    return $finfo->file($filename);
}

header("Content-Type: " . getContentType($filename));
```

Without this, the browser will probably assume that it can't handle the `application/octet-stream` content, and force a download anyway.

You should also only send the `Content-Disposition` header if you want to force the file to be downloaded. If you remove that header, then the browser can decide if it should display the file or download it.